# Method annotated with Spring Kafka listener is not receiving message if previous message processing is blocked

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

In my project, I am using Spring Kafka listener to consume messages from Kafka. I have a doubt that if the consume method code gets blocked due to some reason and never returned back, in this case, will this listener be able to receive new messages and proceed further or it will be hanged? In my case, it looks like, Kafka listener also got blocked and not processing further messages, even, another consumer of same group is also not receiving messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; you will not get more records while a thread is blocked, unless the concurrency is > 1 and there are at least that many partitions. Even then, you will receive no more messages for the partition(s) assigned to the blocked consumer.